# Is there a shortcut to declaring multiple similar automatic properties in c#

Tags: c#, automatic-properties

For instance, I want to declare properties, all of which are strings:

I tried `public string p1, p2, p3 { get; set; }`

Obviously this does not compile, is there an easier way than this one? :

```
public string p1 { get; set; }

public string p2 { get; set; }

public string p3 { get; set; }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Kids these days.  I remember when we had to write out the whole getter / setter with a backing field.  It was also uphill to work, both ways.

Comment: If you don't like typing all of that, Visual Studio has a snippet for this. Type `prop` and hit tab.

Comment: Yes I know the prop snippet, but just wanted to know if an easier way existed, thanks anyways.

Comment: switch to vb, but then you trade one for another.  `Public Property p1 as String` ;)

Answer (score 4):

Automatic properties are already a shortcut for field backed properties, but there is no shortcut for the shortcut :-)

A possible, but stringly typed workaround is to create a single `Dictionary<string,string>` property that can act as a property bag that can be referenced by key (property name). It will save you some typing, but it's not a strongly `typed` solution :-)